# Core Data: constraints changes required migration

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, database-migration

My old ManagedObject model looks like below, with *constraints*: [`trackURL`]

```
@objc(TrackDownloadInfo)
public class TrackDownloadInfo: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged public var trackURL: String
    @NSManaged public var downloadState: Int16
    @NSManaged public var id: Int64
    @NSManaged public var type: Int16

}
```

I just changed *constraints:* [`id`,`type`] without any model version, this causes a migration error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134110 "An error occurred during persistent store migration." UserInfo={sourceURL=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FA440C2E-63EF-4533-94EB-4EA721A645A9/Library/Application%20Support/MyApp.sqlite, reason=Cannot migrate store in-place: constraint violation during attempted migration, destinationURL=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FA440C2E-63EF-4533-94EB-4EA721A645A9/Library/Application%20Support/MyApp.sqlite, NSUnderlyingError=0x2816da820 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134111 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSCoreDataOptimisticLockingFailureConflictsKey=( "" ), NSUnderlyingException=Constraint violation, reason=constraint violation during attempted migration, NSExceptionOmitCallstacks=true}}}, ["NSUnderlyingError": Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134111 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSCoreDataOptimisticLockingFailureConflictsKey=( "" ), NSUnderlyingException=Constraint violation, reason=constraint v

I know it's due to duplicate entries existing in the table with the same `id` and `type` but `trackURL` is different.

I want to delete both entries to migrate it. I didn't fine any way to do this.

Comment: You said you made this change *without any model version*.  If you mean that you did not create a new model version, then that is the problem.  Any changes in a Core Data data model requires a new model version.